# Any Iranian rummers here? What yeast do you use?

Tags: yeast, mead

A lot of Iranians would gladly push away their teetotal laws, and it's evident from the latest alcohol craze which makes me realize there are probably more and more Iranian rummers present in our society, doing God's job, or lack thereof.

I want to know what sort of yeast do you use? I want to brew myself some mead. In a large barrel. What should be the ratio of water and honey, and also, what yeast should I use? Where can I get brewer's yeast?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you add a link to the particular product you are interested in?

Comment: @KenGraham: You mean mead? Or brewer's yeast? I'm interested in any sort of brewer's yeast. Or any yest that does the job.

Answer (score 2):

Bread yeast is very close to brewers yeast.

There is a mead recipe you can search-up: "Joes ancient orange mead", which does specify using bread yeast, rather than specific mead yeast.  Many home brewers make this with good levels of success.

Failing that, you can grow naturally-occurring yeast from the skins of fresh and dried fruits (e.g.: grapes). We used to do this as kids to carbonate ginger beer soft drink (aka: soda).